# Error finding specific user in Active Directory using the C# FindAll method

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, active-directory, directorysearcher

I am trying to search for a specific user in the Active Directory, I am using FindAll method. It is giving me an error when I invoke it. How can I solve this issue?

This is the exception I am getting:

> An unhandled exception of type '**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException**' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll

```
    SearchResultCollection sResults = null;
    try
    {
        //modify this line to include your domain name
        string path = "LDAP://microsistemas.com";
        //init a directory entry
        DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path);

        //init a directory searcher
        DirectorySearcher dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);

        //This line applies a filter to the search specifying a username to search for
        //modify this line to specify a user name. if you want to search for all
        //users who start with k - set SearchString to "k";
        dSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";

        //perform search on active directory
        sResults = dSearcher.FindAll();

        //loop through results of search
        foreach (SearchResult searchResult in sResults)
        {
            if (searchResult.Properties["CN&"][0].ToString() == "Administrator")
            {
                ////loop through the ad properties
                //foreach (string propertyKey in
                //searchResult.Properties["st"])
                //{

                //pull the collection of objects with this key name
                ResultPropertyValueCollection valueCollection =
                searchResult.Properties["manager"];

                foreach (Object propertyValue in valueCollection)
                {

                    //loop through the values that have a specific name
                    //an example of a property that would have multiple
                    //collections for the same name would be memberof
                    //Console.WriteLine("Property Name: " + valueCollection..ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Property Value: " + (string)propertyValue.ToString());

                    //["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString();
                }
                //}
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException iOe)
    {
        //
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException nSe)
    {
        //
    }
    finally
    {

        // dispose of objects used
        if (sResults != null)
            sResults.Dispose();

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with `PrincipalContext`..? also why are you not wrapping your filter text around `" "` vs using `dSearcher.Filter = &quot;(&amp;(objectClass=user))&quot;;` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace.

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context - limit to the OU you're interested in
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, "DC=microsistemas,DC=com"))
{
    // find a user
    Principal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....     
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Read more about it here:

- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)